# VBA Excel Value not recorded/accepted in IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a problem with IE not accepting a value (the name of a computer) that I am trying to put into a field. I set the value, it becomes visible in the field, but then when I click "Submit" on the form, it (IE) fails to recognize the value I entered. I am able to modify other objects on the page, but not this simple text field. I can even retrieve the Value from the object in IE after setting it. The field is required, so the submit routine fails before I can proceed.

Here's some code:

```
'Find the correct instance of IE
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
' etc.
Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
' etc.

' Enter Computer_Name
Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(2).contentDocument.getElementById("QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC")
objCollection.Value = Computer_Name ' (The text I'm trying to enter)

' Some other stuff that is working

' Click the "Submit" button on the form (this works too).
```

After clicking "Submit", the webpage pops up an error saying that the required field (the computer name) was not entered. The field is highlighted red.

When I enter the computer name manually, it works just fine, but not when using VBA. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is a sample of the HTML code. I'll highlight the element I'm trying to modify.

```
<div class="questionContainer ">
    <div class="left questionBody" id="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC-label-body" required="false">
        <label class="questionlabel bold" id="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC-label" for="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC">Computer Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="left answerBody block">
        <div class="left">
            <div id="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC-answer-body">
' *********** The next line is the element in question. ************
                <input tabindex="0" class="answerTextarea " id="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC" aria-describedby="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC-instructions" aria-labelledby="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC-label" required="true" type="text" size="40" value="" responsetype="TEXT" questiondefid="QDHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CE" totalorder="3" questionid="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC" level="0" overwrite="1" maxlng="16" wrap="virtual">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="validationResult clear" id="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC-validationResult" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="instructions" id="QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC-instructions"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Possibly important note: the bit of code in one of the later lines of code that says "style="display: none;" does not appear until the value is entered into the filed manually in IE.

Thanks!

Comment: Likely worth checking to see if that field has dynamically-added event handlers (keydown? keypress?) which are triggered by typing into the field but not when changing the value using VBA.

Comment: If you dont mind. Could you please share the URL as well so that we can test it.

Comment: @Tim Williams: Thank you. Good ideas! How do I check for dynamically-added event handlers? Where can I go to learn about them? objCollection.KeyPress or objCollection.KeyDown give "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method."

Comment: @user2851376: Thank you for offering to help test the web site. Unfortunately this site requires a company-specific certificate to access. I can post HTML code though.

Comment: Maybe try using this?  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#geteventlistenersobject

Comment: The events I can see happening are mousedown, mouseup, click, textInput, change, focus, mouseup, and a few others. I can perform "objCollection.Select", but "objCollection.MouseDown" etc. do not work. (I'm probably displaying my ignorance here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Tim Williams for your help with ideas which put me on the journey that led to this solution. It turned out that I needed to trigger the events for the page to accept the value. Amazingly simple, when I come to realize it. Here is what my final code looks like:

```
Dim objEvent ' **** NEW ****

'Find the correct instance of IE (opened manually initially)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
' etc.
Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
' etc. (including navigation when necessary)

' After the webpage has loaded, set the event handler ' **** NEW ****
Set objEvent = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents") ' **** NEW ****

' Enter Computer_Name
Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(2).contentDocument.getElementById("QSHAA5V0GH4LSAO2AI6F2MXNIAJ5CC")
objCollection.Value = Computer_Name ' (The text I'm entering)
' Trigger the event change ' **** NEW ****
objEvent.initEvent "change", False, True ' **** NEW ****
objCollection.dispatchEvent objEvent ' **** NEW ****

' Enter other needed information

' Click the "Submit" button on the form.
```